# Idea 13 and Gradle when trying to use scala-compiler in the Scala facets does not find scala-library

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I would like to use in my project the scala-compiler from Gradle dependencies but when I try to use it I get:

[image]

Am I using the wrong dependency? Why scala-library is not found? Here is my build:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    def hamcrestVersion = "1.3"
    def jmockVersion = "2.6.0"
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.0-rc0',
            'org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:0.106',
            'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3',
            'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.3'

    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:2.1.0',
            'junit:junit:4.11',
            'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:1.42',
            "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:${hamcrestVersion}",
            "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:${hamcrestVersion}",
            "org.jmock:jmock:${jmockVersion}"
    testCompile("org.jmock:jmock-junit4:${jmockVersion}") {
        exclude group: "junit"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you apply the `idea` plugin (to `allprojects` in a multi-project build), this should be set up automatically. That's definitely the case when generating IDE files with `gradle idea`. (Not sure if it also works when using IDEA's Gradle plugin to import the build.) Unless your own code depends on it, it isn't necessary to have `scala-compiler` on the compile class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you can modify the entry of the gradle generated library by adding scala-library*.jar e scala-reflect*.jar

It works but it's an ugly workaround (wich probably you will have ot do again and again when you change the project dependencies in the gradle file)

Comment: It's not a lasting solution.

Comment: I hope that such kind of issues will be addressed directly by the development team

Comment: If you think you've found something which needs fixing on Gradle's side, please submit an issue over at http://forums.gradle.org. For IDE related problems, you could also submit an issue in IntelliJ's bug tracker.